# Array without undefined validation with io-ts

Tags: typescript, validation

We are using [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) to validate external data from HTTP services. I have written a codec that takes another codec `C` and returns `Either<t.Errors, C | undefined>` but actually never fails (just to satisfy `t.Type`). This is because from the service we get an array of different types and new ones can be added in the future so we want it to continue working but just ignore those that are undefined. Looks like:

```js
export function tryDecode<C extends io.Mixed>(
  codec: C,
  onLeft?: (validation: io.Validation<unknown>) => void,
) {
  return new io.Type<io.TypeOf<C> | undefined, io.OutputOf<C>, unknown>(
    'tryDecode',
    (input: unknown): input is C | undefined => {
      return codec.is(input) || input === undefined;
    },
    (u, c) => {
      const validation = codec.validate(u, c);

      return fold(
        () => {
          if (onLeft) {
            onLeft(validation);
          }

          return io.success(undefined as C | undefined);
        },
        (right: C | undefined) => io.success(right),
      )(validation);
    },
    io.identity,
  );
}
```

I am trying to write a codec `arrayWithoutUndefined` that works just like `io.array` but removes any element that is undefined. It should not fail (unless it's not an array). My attempt so far:

```js
export function arrayWithoutUndefined<C extends io.Mixed>(
  codec: C,
  name = `arrayWithoutUndefined<${codec.name}>`,
) {
  const arr = io.array(codec);

  return new io.Type(
    name,
    (u): u is Array<io.TypeOf<C>> => arr.is(u) && !u.includes(undefined),
    (u, c) =>
      either.chain(codec.validate(u, c), as =>
        io.success(as.filter(notUndefined)),
      ),
    arr.encode,
  );
}
```

The `notUndefined` is a helper that ensures `(a: A | undefined): a is A => ...`. Then I would use them together as `const Modules = arrayWithoutUndefined(tryDecode(UnionOfDifferentModules))` but Modules is still expressed as `Array<UnionOfDifferentModules | undefined>` when I want it to just be `Array<UnionOfDifferentModules>`. Is this possible to express with TypeScript/io-ts somehow? I looked into conditional types but unfortunately have no idea how to express.

Answer (score 1):

This problem may have solved itself [in newer versions of typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7657) that support type guards in array filter statements.

It's also possible that explicit generics for the `t.Type` would help here.

```js
type Subtract<A, B> = A extends B ? never : A;

return io.Type<Subtract<t.TypeOf<C>, undefined>, unknown[], unknown>(...);
```